# How to append a char type variable to a string?

Tags: c++

I want to append a char-variable containing the password to a string saying "Your password is: ". When I use the append function for this I get an error saying I can't use this function with string. (I can only use it with unsigned int and char.)

```
char pass[64];
std::cout << "Enter a password: "; fgets(pass, 64, stdin);    
std::string ssifre = "Your password is: "; ssifre.append(sizeof(pass), pass);
```

If you know another way to solve this, please comment. I don't need to use this function.

Comment: You mean ssifre.append(pass);

Comment: terrible mix C and C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
ssifre += pass;
```

It's using the [+= operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)

(note that as @MichaelDoubez mentionned in the comments, `ssifre.append(pass)` would work, too.)

Answer (score 0):

`ssifre.append(sizeof(pass), pass)` is trying to call the `append(size_type count, CharT ch)` overloaded version, which appends `ch` count times.  That does not work since `pass[]` is not a single `char`, it is an array of chars.

You need to use the `append(const CharT* s)` overloaded version instead (especially since `fgets()` ensures that `pass[]` will be null-terminated, and `append(const CharT* s)` expects a null-terminated `char*` string).  A fixed `char[]` array decays into a `char*` pointer to the 1st `char` element:

```
ssifre.append(pass);
```

That being said, you really shouldn't be using a `char[]` array in this situation to begin with.  You should be reading in a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string pass;
std::cout << "Enter a password: ";
std::getline(std::cin, pass);
std::string ssifre = "Your password is: " + pass;
```